# solving expression for $Y$ in terms of $X$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently trying to solve the following expression to obtain $Y$ in terms of $X$:

$$Y^{-1/2} + \sqrt{Y^{-1} + a} = \exp(-b(d \pm \sqrt2 X)),$$
where $a$, $b$ and $d$ are constants. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What makes you think it's possible? I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use substitutions $u = y^{-1}$ and $b = \exp (-b(d \pm \sqrt{2} X)$ you get
$$ \sqrt{u}+\sqrt{u+a} = b,$$ which, in turn can be transformed to (but beware of extraneous solutions after squaring both sides): $$ 4u^2 + 4au = (2u-b^2+a)^2.$$
Substituting again $g = b^2-a$:
$$ (4a+4g) u = g^2 \longrightarrow u = \frac{g^2}{4a+4g} = \frac{1}{y}
\longrightarrow  y = \frac{4a+4g}{g^2}.$$
Now plug in the substituted values and you get your solutions.

Comment: Using the notation $b$ for two different things is a bit misleading (the original problem already involves a $b$ in it).